AmE_ I worked/ have worked with 3 different tech companies
In an interview, when I introduce myself, I would say:
(1) I worked with 3 different tech companies, so I have a lot of experience in IT
(2) I have worked with 3 different tech companies, so I have a lot of experience in IT
I think that I can use both. Right?

Have worked emphasizes acquiring and holding knowledge — key in an interview — as opposed to some past accomplishment. Also, I have a thing against different tech companies. They couldn't be 3 of the same, so different is tautology: "I have worked with 3 tech companies."

Your so-clause makes it obvious that having worked with three different tech companies is extremely relevant to the current conversation, so Present Perfect is the natural choice (because "relevance to time of utterance" is the primary justification for using Present Perfect). Simple Past is syntactically valid and effectively means the same thing without the implied relevance, but idiomatically it's unlikely.

Both of these can be used in any variety of English. There is no difference between American English and other varieties here.  Which to choose would depend on context. For example: are you still working with a tech company or were you up until recently, or was it a while ago in the past?  The present perfect is generally used to talk about things in the past, but which have an effect in the present/up until the present.

@BillyKerr, I want to add more details to the context: In the years of 2010, 2011, 2012, I worked in 3 tech companies respectively. Now I don't work for any tech companies. At the moment of an interview, I want to tell the employer about my previous jobs:**
I (worked)/ (have worked) with 3 different tech companies, so I have a lot of experience in IT.
**Do you think that I can use both in this context, and the present perfect is more likely to use, but the simple past is not wrong?

Thanks for the extra info. I would say that given the context you've described: during an interview, it would probably be more common in all standard varieties of English to use the present perfect here, since you are kind of talking about past experiences which are relevant to the present interview.  If you were just telling a story, the simple past would be fine.

@BillyKerr I (bought)/ (have bought) a new car, would you like to try driving? Here I think that both are fine and equally likely to be used. Buying the car is relevant to the present, but the simple past is still good to use in this context, But why in the context of an interview only the present perfect is good to used?

As usual, it depends on context. The sentence I have worked with three different tech companies… is far the better if you are summarizing all of your relevant history. You could think of it as though it had an unspoken (but implied) preamble, So far, over the course of my life.
The I worked version suggests …during some period, so it might be appropriate in a response to a question like Please discuss any relevant work experience you acquired while you were a student.
So if the context is your opening remarks—and thus absent any restriction of time period (explicit or implicit)—then the I worked version is not at all idiomatic.

if so, in the US, the version (1) with simple past is wrong in this context. Right?

Wrong? I don’t know that I would necessarily go quite that far. But I would indeed counsel very strongly against it if your intent is to use standard English.

I think that both can be used, the there are small difference like this: (1) with simple past emphasizes what I did in my previous jobs// (2) emphasizes what is my experience now.
Is my reasoning correct?

No, your reasoning is not correct. The simple past (here, I worked) implies “at some moment” or “during some period.” Thus things like Yesterday, I worked a 10-hour shift. By contrast, the present perfect (here, I have worked) describes a current fact about things that have happened before—and in some contexts, right up to—the moment of its uttering.

When you are discussing a particular job, you would use the simple past (so At Google I worked on human-factors design). But when explaining everything that you have done over your entire life, it’s the present perfect. (Note that in my own previous sentence I wrote, “everything that you have done,” not “everything that you did.”) This is how English works.

The moment you die, your survivors will switch from He has worked at five companies to He worked at five companies. This is because it will no longer be a current fact: you will no longer be around to have anything, let alone to have worked. [And assuming that he is the correct pronoun. She? They? You get the idea.]

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/606897/ame-the-use-of-the-simple-past-and-the-present-perfect-in-the-us-for-repeated-a

in the link above, as Lambie's answer, we can use the simple past, but why can't we use the simple past in this case.

I visited/ have visited Paris two times. It is a beautiful city. I think you should visit it once in your life.

is this because the difference in dialects?

As @Lambie explains in her answer to the question you linked, the simple past is used in the context of a specific instant or period. This has nothing to do with dialects. I visited Paris twice will leave any native speaker of English wondering, “When?”—unless that when is clear from context. As I wrote above, this is how English works.

IMVHO, considering this answer I would be tempted to say that
you want to emphasize what happened rather than when,
so form (2) may sounds better.
Despite this, I must admit that I am not totally sure...

You should be sure of your facts if you decide to post an answer! (As a British English speaker I would certainly use (2), but the OP asked about American usage, which may be more tolerant of (1)).
